# Why does Puppet need two runs to update bash?

Tags: puppet

Im learning puppet, and Im trying to update bash (no prizes for guessing why).

This is in my site.pp

```
       file { "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/shellshock.list":
            source  => "puppet:///files/shellshock.list",
            owner   => "root",
            group   => "root",
            mode    => "0644", 
            ensure  => present,
    } 
    ->
exec { "instantRepoUpdate":
        command          => "/usr/bin/aptitude update",
        refreshonly  => true,
}
    ->
    package {"bash": ensure => latest, }
```

From what Im reading here https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_relationships.html
That should translate to:

Install `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/shellshock.list`, then run aptitude update, then make sure bash is on the latest version

It does, but only over two runs of the agent. I want it to perform all three actions, in order, in one run.

UPDATE: I've tried adding "require => Exec[.., require => File[..." to the exec and package resources, I get the same result.

Comment: I *think* the first arrow needs to be a notification arrow (`~>`) since you've set `refreshonly => true`

Comment: @faker. Spot on! Thank you Sir! Add it as an answer and make sure it gets accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set `refreshonly => true` and as such you need to use a notification arrow instead (`~>`).

Comment: Violently disagree with the final assertion. `ensure => latest` **will** take effect, notification received or no. It may be a noop if `aptitude` is not aware of the new version in time, but that is another matter.

Comment: Hm are you sure? Even if there is a chaining arrow from the exec?

Comment: Yes, the `package` will be skipped if the `file` or `exec` fails, but an event from either of them is of no consequence.

Comment: @FelixFrank You are right, thanks for pointing it out! Removed from the answer.